# DatagramChannel receive may not return SocketAddress

Tags: java, nio, datagram

According to the Javadoc for DatagramChannel the receive method:

```
public abstract SocketAddress receive(ByteBuffer dst)
                           throws IOException
```

may return null if the DatagramChannel is in non-blocking mode.  Other than changing to blocking mode is there a way to ensure I get the SocketAddress for the data I read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> may return null if the DatagramChannel is in non-blocking mode.

[Read on](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/DatagramChannel.html#receive(java.nio.ByteBuffer)).

> Returns ... `null` if this channel is in non-blocking mode and no datagram was immediately available.

If it returned null there was no data read. The situation corresponds to `SocketChannel.read()` returning zero.

Comment: ok, so it's not possible to receive data without a SocketAddress, I wasn't sure.